# How to bring registration field to index page?

Tags: buddypress, forms, user-registration

I am using wordpress and buddypress for my site and my registration works perfectly on www.mysite.com/register, i need to bring the registration fields to the home page(index.php). My register page contains 6 about fields, i tried to bring this, but i couldn't do so and i am stuck with this, could anyone know the solution.

Comment: Have you looked to see if there is any widgets that could perform this task? might be worth having a look then defining a new widget area on your template.

Comment: @vince iam searching for it, but i couldn't find one.

Answer (score 0):

I've not had chance to test it but after a very brief google search I found this - http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/registration-form-widget/

This could be the answer if it works, you could create a new widget area within your page template and then drop the widget in to that area and style the widget to suite.